# Java Heap Space Issue while running Junits

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, ehcache

I have been working on upgrading an application from Spring 3 to 4 and Hibernate 3 to 4. Exact version now:
Spring : 4.1.9
Hibernate: 4.3.7

Due to dependencies I am also having to upgrade the Junit version and we are using 4.12 now.

Since the upgrade I am getting a java heap space exception for most of the unit tests:

```
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:361)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.&lt;init&gt;(CacheManager.java:237)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:856)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:743)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getInstance(CacheManager.java:758)
    at com.rsa.csd.RsaBaseTestCase.setUp(RsaBaseTestCase.java:144)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry.newArray(ConcurrentHashMap.java:226)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.&lt;init&gt;(ConcurrentHashMap.java:316)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap$MemoryStoreSegment.&lt;init&gt;(SelectableConcurrentHashMap.java:270)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap$MemoryStoreSegment.&lt;init&gt;(SelectableConcurrentHashMap.java:262)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap.createSegment(SelectableConcurrentHashMap.java:245)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.ConcurrentHashMap.&lt;init&gt;(ConcurrentHashMap.java:634)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap.&lt;init&gt;(SelectableConcurrentHashMap.java:52)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore.&lt;init&gt;(MemoryStore.java:146)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore.&lt;init&gt;(NotifyingMemoryStore.java:37)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore.create(NotifyingMemoryStore.java:49)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryOnlyStore.create(MemoryOnlyStore.java:69)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.initialise(Cache.java:1105)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.initializeEhcache(CacheManager.java:1128)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:1159)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addConfiguredCaches(CacheManager.java:708)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:426)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:352)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.&lt;init&gt;(CacheManager.java:237)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:856)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:743)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getInstance(CacheManager.java:758)
    at com.rsa.csd.RsaBaseTestCase.setUp(RsaBaseTestCase.java:144)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:133)
```

I have tried searching online but havent been able to find any solution.

Please let me know whatever config files I need to post.

Comment: Which version of ehcache is in use? I would update to use the latest 2.x version. Then, do you have an `ehcache.xml` file?

Comment: I am using ehcache 2.5. Have no access to the office laptop right now..so will share the file as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You go to the run configurations and then under arguments, you can set the `vm arguments`. Within the arguments tab set VM arguments to `"-Xms64m -Xmx256m"` or higher depends on your system configuration.

Comment: Have tried that, I have even set it as high as 4 gb and still get the same exception.

Comment: What ide you are using ?  if you are using eclipse, increse the memory allocated to eclipse in eclipse.ini.

Comment: I am getting this issue even when I run the test case from command prompt, so not sure if this is an eclipse related issue.

Comment: Then you will have to look at the heap dumb. Use VisualVM to read the heap dump file and diagnose the issue. VisualVM is a program located in JDK_HOME/bin/jvisualvm. The heap dump file has all information about the memory usage of the application. It allows you to navigate the heap and see which objects use the most memory and what references prevent the garbage collector from reclaiming the memory.

Comment: Sure will give that a try and get back. Thanks